# Folder permission .htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I am creating a php website, I want to protect my css file. So that if any user tried to open it directly in browser, he won't be able to see the code for this. I have created .htaccess file and wrote

```
 # no one gets in here!
deny from all

ErrorDocument 403 "You dont have sufficient priviliges to view this page.
```

But now my css is not at all rendering in any pages. How can i acheive this functionality?

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I want to secure my css code,nobody can see my css code

Comment: What's so much in your CSS that you want to secure? We have consoles..

Comment: @user3106347 You *can't* do that. It's **impossible**. If your browser can download the CSS (it has to), then *anyone* can. That's how the internet works.

Comment: @Jonathon!!! Can we give some permission type thing?

Comment: how do you think the browser can render your page if it cannot see your css file? think of browser as a person

Comment: @ bansi i want browser can render the css file,but user cant see it by typing localhost/project/css/style.css

Comment: I think you missed my previous comment. **What you are asking for is impossible**. Your browser *has to* be able to download it, in the *exact* same way a human would by entering the URL. This is how the Internet works. Look up GET requests.

Comment: the browser is doing the exact thing as the user typing at the address bar and getting the page.

Comment: @user3106347 That is simply impossible. You need to understand how Internet works in order to understand why it is impossible.

Comment: @ Jonathon Reinhart  !!! can we decode css file

Comment: yes you can, but you have to send the decoder first to the browser. which will defeat your purpose as human can also download it. and it will be slow and ugly, no user may visit your page second time. BTW why you want to hide your CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Protecting files via `.htaccess`, will prevent them from opening via browser. Therefore when browser will try to load this file to render CSS it will not be able to access it.

Somehow obvious - no?

In addition - CSS, HTML, JavaScript files cannot be protected from opening them in browser, because in order to serve their purpose those should be accessible from browser...

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% foolproof but you can do this via HTTP_REFERER check.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

Replace `yourdomain\.com` with your actual domain name.

*Now your own pages will be able to access css, js, image files but externally these files cannot be accessed*

Comment: That is in no way protection... But for someone who does not know how web browser works it will do the trick. Still those who know how to open CSS in browser will be able to access it...

Comment: @AlexKey You mean using Firebug / Inspect element?

Comment: You can see how I started my answer `Not 100% foolproof`. But it will still block majority of users who don't know how to hack `HTTP_REFERER` header.

Comment: @HussainTamboli Yes, and also if browser once loaded CSS, it will remain cached, and second time (if you just type URL in), it will not be requested from server, but shown from local cache (this will work not in all browsers tho)

Comment: no need to hack `HTTP_REFERER` header, you can always get the CSS easily from the browser's view source

Comment: @anubhava my point is the same as Hussain said - firebug, inspector will still be working.

Comment: @AlexKey: Blocking based on `HTTP_REFERER` is a well known trick to block image hot-linking all over the web. Read more about it by searching on Google `"apache prevent image hotlinking"` and see what results you get.

Comment: @bansi: An outsider cannot get the `http://domain.com/css/style.css` only site's pages can get. Of course a regular user who is already visiting `domain.com` can get to see any JS/CSS since that is how page is rendered by client browser.